# Can't copy or past files in other locations in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, disk-usage, file-sharing, read-only, 21.10

I have installed Ubuntu in my laptop by partitioning HDD, but now I couldn't copy or past files in other locations of my lap it's showing

"Error while copying, the destination is read-only".

Why is that????

Comment: What do you mean by other locations? Please be specific. Also, stop with the emoji, it looks awful and makes your question harder to read.

Comment: Currently I am using Ubuntu 21.10 in which when we open files there is option available as **Other Locations**  on bottom last where we can find other drives in pc I couldn't transfer files to that location, even can't create new folder in that location please help if you know solution brother.

Comment: Is that "other location" a windows drive?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a couple issues: the UUID of the filesystem might be the same or it could be that the filesystem is read only because it's not mounted with the correct command. I checked the tags and saw dual boot so that's a possibility.

To check the UUID use (If the external UUID is the same as the internal continue, if not go to solution 2)`

```
sudo blkid
```

Now use a file system check on the respective external filesystem as super user.

```
e2fsck -f -p -C 0 /dev/sda5
```

Show me the results.

**Now here is the second solution if the UUID is different.**

First Type in

```
id
```

to get the uid and gid of the following command.

```
sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/sdc1
```

***CHECK GPARTED FOR THE FILESYSTEM IN QUESTION***

`